ASP.NET Core site hosted in new IIS instance now having CryptographicException issues
We recently moved our ASP.NET Core 6.0 site off an old Windows 2012 IIS 8.5 installation to our new Windows 2022 server running IIS 10.0.20348.1 and everything for the most part is working how it should.
The only issue I'm seeing is an occasional System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException warning, "The key {GUID} was not found in the key ring." with the message of "The temp data cookie ".AspNetCore.Mvc.CookieTempDataProvider" could not be loaded."
This in turn causes an Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.AntiforgeryValidationException error to be thrown "The antiforgery token could not be decrypted."
I'm seeing this occur in two places. The first being when our users Log in using the built in ASP.NET Core Identity middleware, and secondly when a View Component places a basic String into TempData.
I've tried searching and made a few changes, such as setting the "LoadUserProfile" value to true on the Application Pool, but the issues are still showing up in my logs. I'm not seeing the issue with every request either, making it harder for me to try to track down and resolve.
Is this a transient issue that will resolve itself as fewer and fewer of our users arrive to the "new" site with "old" site cookies? Or is there some other bigger issue that I've failed to find and fix.
Thanks!

You can try to add detailed logging around the areas where this issue occurs (i.e., temp data and antiforgery validation). Logging key details such as user session details or cookie information may help you identify patterns in the failures.

it does sound like a cookie issue, so you could catch those errors and force those users to re-login and eventually the issue will resolve.  There are also settings for persisting the keyring, but if you do that at this point new cookies would be affected.  I believe the keys will have a lifetime of 90 days.  (so expired keys are still in the keyring, but won't be used for generating new encrypted cookies such as anti-forgery tokens)  The anti-forgery tokens are generated per request, but they are checked against a per session-derived cookie.  (some sessions are tied to old keyring?)

If it's practical you could also tell the users to delete their existing cookies.
